# What are these two items sticking out of Soyuz capsule MS-13 with returning Expedition 61 Crew?

Tags: identify-this-object, soyuz-spacecraft

At `18:55`and `19:00` in NASA Videos' [NASA Television Video File- MS 13 Hatch Closing Undocking Landing - February 6, 2020](https://youtu.be/1B9wroefbJw) what looks like a white LED light blinks on the Soyuz capsule from an opening. From the same opening is some ~50 cm long rod-like structure sticking out about 30 degrees from vertical, with something hanging from it.

The blinking light and rod are annotated as [1] and [2] respectively in the screenshots

**Question:** What are these, how did they get there, and what are their functions?

[[image: Soyuz capsule screen shot NASA Television Video File- MS 13]]

[image: Soyuz capsule screen shot NASA Television Video File- MS 13]

[image: Soyuz capsule screen shot NASA Television Video File- MS 13]

Comment: Think it's answered here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12067/6944 Flashing light beacon & radio beacon antenna. Possible duplicate.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's at least part of the answer. To "how did they get there" do they just pop out automatically? Is that stated clearly in an answer there?

Comment: I'll close the question as duplicate; I'm just going to assume a cover popped off and the antenna automatically extended.